# On convergence of functions and sequences

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x) = f(x),\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

We also assume that we have a sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = a.$$

Under what conditions do we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(a_n) = f(a)\ ?$$

I can see that if the functions were continuous, it would be true.
I wonder if there exist a general result for this.

Answer (score 1):

$(f_n(a_n)-f(a))-(f(a_n)-f(a))=(f_n(a_n)-f(a_n))$. So, for example, a satisfactory condition could be, $f_n$ is uniformly convergent to $f$ in a neighbourhood of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is continuous and $f_n \to f$ uniformly then this is true.

Proof: Suppose $f_n(a_n)$ does not tend to $f(a)$. Then there exists a subsequence $(a_{n_i})$ and $r >0$ such that $|f_{n_i}(a_{n_i})-f(a)| >r$ for all $i$. Uniform convergence now shows that $|f_(a_{n_i})-f(a)| \geq |f_{n_i}(a_{n_i})-f(a)| - |f_{n_i}(a_{n_i})-f(a_{n_i})|  >\frac  r 2$ for $j$ sufficiently large. But this contradicts the fact that $f$ is continuous at $a$.

The converse of this result is also true if you restrict your attention  to a compact interval $[-A,A]$.

Answer (score 0):

No, assuming just that the functions are continuous is not enough. Say $$f_n(t)=\begin{cases}0,&(t<0),
\\nt,&(0\le t<1/n),
\\2-nt,&(1/n\le t<2/n),
\\0,&(t\ge 2/n)\end{cases}$$

and set $f(t)=0$,  $a_n=1/n$.